# Website Navigation Bar: Displaying webpages while retaining the highlighted menu

Tags: php, html, css

Sorry if the title seems confusing or anything... I can't figure out what to put..

I'm actually a newbie but I've tried building a simple website in php before but back then I was just copying my navigation code to my every page and put 'current' to it so everytime, for example you are in the HOME page, the menu HOME in the nav bar is highlighted... now I tried following this tutorial to build my nav bar>http://dbwebb.se/kod-exempel/dynamic_php_menu/

I've got it but my problem is I don't know how to display my other pages when clicking the menu item...

I tried changing the 'url' to product.php (my products page)

```
<?php
$menu = array(
  'home'  => array('text'=> '<img class="brighten"; src="style/images/home-hover.png"/>',  'url'=>'?p=home'),
  'products'  => array('text'=>'Products',  'url'=>'products.php'),
  'about' => array('text'=>'About', 'url'=>'about.php'),
);
?>
```

It displays the product page but the menu item 'Products' is not highlighted

btw my navigation bar is a separate php file and I just 'include' it in my other pages...

So how can I highlight the current choice while navigating to my 'Products' page?

I apologize if my question and explanation of the problem is confusing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simply check the file you pass as variable to select thr page. And if the current page is products for example. You add this class (I didn't viewed the link you gave, that's just the way I do it ..